# I can't import new modules in Jupyter Notebook on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, module, jupyter-notebook

The value of `sys.executable` is  `/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10`  on both Jupyter Notebook and the Terminal.
However `pip3 list` in the terminal gives me a different list than `help('modules')` in Jupyter Notebook

I think Jupyter gets my modules from `/Users/matdou/virtualenvs/Jupyter` but i think I deleted the path by mistake in $PATH one day. Now my modules go somewhere else.

How can I fix this problem ?

Another thing I don't get is this error message when I use pip :

`WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.8 are installed in '/Users/matdou/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, pip3 was using python2.7, problem solved !